# Windows 7 Internet Explorer cannot start

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd, internet-explorer

I have a 128GB SSD with Windows 7 installed. But I can't always install programs and games on that drive so I changed the Program Files location from C:\ (SSD) drive to D:\ (SATA) drive.

Everything's OK except Internet EXplorer. After I changed the default Program Files location, I can't even start it. Or it will crash when I double clicked the icon.

Before I set the default location, I have installed Chrome and copied all C:\Program Files to D:\Program Files. So everything's run smoothly but not the IE.

Can anybody teach me how to fix this? (except changing back the default Program Files to C:\ unless it is the only way, but the way I see there should be a solution because everybody just like me)

Comment: Microsoft does not support or recommend changing the locations of the program files folders. The option is provided for exceptional situations and is not appropriate for general use. There are known issues with this. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/933700/microsoft-does-not-support-changing-the-location-of-the-program-files-folder-by-modifying-the-programfilesdir-registry-value

Comment: Maybe create symbolic links to the "D" drive locations in the expected "C" drive location for a starting point potentially.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Microsoft Internet Explorer troubleshooter that might fix up your problem with IE. You can download troubleshooter from following link. 
[Download Internet Explorer troubleshooter](http://aka.ms/diag_maintenance10).

If problem still persists then you may try reinstalling internet explorer from scratch. To reinstall it follow the following steps.

1. Navigate to control panel
2. Search for Windows features.
3. From search results click on Turn Windows features on or off.
4. On Windows features window uncheck the box of Internet Explorer 10.  And click on OK. You might get warning link turning off this feature may effect other feature. Click on OK.
5. After its done. Restart the PC.
6. And download the new installer of internet explorer from following link. 
   [Download Internet Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/17621/internet-explorer-downloads).